# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'serviceId' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

Iam using nested json as input to Angular 6 where below is what my json structure looks like:

```
{"contractId":1,"contractName":"Temp","contractServiceList":[{"id":1,"serviceId":{"serviceId":1,"serviceName":"Emergency Room"},"providerTier":"Tier 1","coinsurance":100.0,"copay":10.0,"penaltyApplies":"Y","penaltyRule":"Non Emergency ER Use","penaltyType":"Dollar Amount","penaltyValue":300.0,"deductibleApplies":"Y"}]}
```

In component.ts, my code is:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  services: Service;
  serviceId: ServiceId[];
  contract: Contract[];
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private router: Router, private contractService: ContractService) {  }

  addForm: FormGroup;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.serviceId = [
    {serviceId: '1', serviceName: 'Emergency Room'},
    {serviceId: '2', serviceName: 'OP Radiology'}
  ];
```

component.html :

```
 <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="serviceName">Category Of Services:</label>
      <select id ="serviceName" formControlName="serviceName" name="serviceName" class="form-control">
    <option *ngFor="let serv of serviceId" [value]="serv.serviceId">{{serv.serviceName}}</option>
</select>
      </div>
```

I am submitting all the values in the form as (ngSubmit)="onSubmit" and subscribing it as below:

```
 onSubmit() {
    this.contractService.saveContract(this.addForm.value)
      .subscribe( data => {
alert('Contract created successfully');
      });
}
```

Not sure why it's not able to take serviceId value. Any help is appreciable!!

Comment: where are you getting the error

Comment: I am able to figure out somewhat. Actually I am working on saving data from Angular in the format of nested json and now I landed up with the actual cause which is showing up in console.log the below data: {"contractId":0,"contractName":"XYZ","contractServiceList":null} which means I am not able to post the data in the inner list. I am using form submit as onSubmit() {
    this.contractService.saveContract(this.addForm.value)
      .subscribe( data => {
        alert('Contract created successfully');
        console.log(data);
      });
  } .subscribe only gives outer list, inner is null

Comment: below data means what?

Comment: below data means - Json format is expected as I pasted in the initial part of this thread but actually getting  {"contractId":0,"contractName":"XYZ","contractServiceList":null} which is showing inner list is not taken

Comment: For more clarity, this is the code where I am getting inner list asnull. onSubmit() {
    this.contractService.saveContract(this.addForm.value)
      .subscribe( data => {
        alert('Contract created successfully');
        console.log(data);
      });
  }

Comment: your question is not clear yet though

Comment: In simple terms, how can I subscribe the data so that it should go in http.post as this json format: {"contractId":1,"contractName":"Temp","contractServiceList":[{"id":1,"serviceId":{"serviceId":1,"serviceName":"Emergency Room"},"providerTier":"Tier 1","coinsurance":100.0,"copay":10.0,"penaltyApplies":"Y","penaltyRule":"Non Emergency ER Use","penaltyType":"Dollar Amount","penaltyValue":300.0,"deductibleApplies":"Y"}]}